# Angular + Laravel PHP Routing in .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, angular, angular-routing

Доброго времени суток.

Have some trouble.

Есть сайт на Angular и сервер на PHP (Laravel).

Заказчик попросил убрать # из урла, после этого при обновлении страницы ловим 404.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: false }),
```

Посмотрел, как это решается (Методом конфигурации файла .htaccess), но не помогло, ибо там конфликты с PHP.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Файлы index.html и index.php лежат в одной директории - /var/www/satu/public
Могу ли я как-то решить эту проблему через файл .htaccess, не меняя местоположение файлов, или надо сделать что-то еще?

Спасибо.

routes/web.php

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});

// Route for parse CSV files to DB
Route::get('/parseData', 'ParseController@parse');
Route::get('/parseImages', 'ParseController@addImages');

Route::get('/login', 'Web\LoginController@loginForm')->name('loginForm');
Route::post('/login', 'Web\LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('/logout', 'Web\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('/register', 'Web\LoginController@registerForm')->name('registerForm');
Route::post('/register', 'Web\LoginController@register')->name('register');
Route::post('/check-phone', 'Web\LoginController@checkPhone')->name('check_phone');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1.0', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1_0', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
    Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/web/login', 'LoginController@webLogin');
    Route::post('/register', 'LoginController@register');
    Route::post('/confirm-phone', 'LoginController@confirmPhone');
    Route::post('/resend-confirm-sms', 'LoginController@resendConfirmSms');
    Route::post('/recovery-code-send', 'LoginController@sendRecoveryPasswordCode');
    Route::post('/recovery-password', 'LoginController@recoveryPassword');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
        Route::get('/user', 'LoginController@user')->name('api.user');
        Route::put('/user', 'LoginController@userUpdate')->name('api.user.update');
        Route::post('/contracts/verify', 'PaymentsScheduleController@verify');
        Route::get('/notifications', 'NotificationController@notificationsList');
        Route::put('/user/token', 'LoginController@updateToken');
    });
});

Route::get('/api/soap/logs', 'Web\LogsController@showLogs')->name('admin.soap.logs');
Route::get('/api/soap/fix', 'Web\LogsController@fixLogs')->name('admin.soap.fix');

Route::get('/postman', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('index');
```

Comment: мдаа. Зачем было `/api/*` маршруты сюда писать... для них есть отдельный файл `routes/api.php`...  Ну да ладно. Маршрут `/postman` работает?

Comment: @Максим-К Хороший вопрос.) В данном случае я не писал ни бэк, ни фронт. Да, работает.

Comment: Попробуй вместо `/postman` указать `/{all}`, а после `->name('index')->where('all', '.*');`

Comment: @Максим-К Мне кажется я сделал что-то не совсем то.) При обновлении любой страницы выходит welcome от постмана.) - Route::get('/{all}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('index')->where('all', '.*');

Comment: Короче, надо, чтобы указанный маршрут выдавал разметку для инициализации фронта - DOM элемент для монтирования и подключение собранных шрифтов/стилей. Остальное фронт должен сам делать на основе Текущей страницы. Какой вообще адрес страницы, после которого хэш-маршрутизация осуществляется на фронте?

Answer (score 2):

Это SPA с маршрутизацией по history api.
По поводу фронта ничего не скажу, но по бэку `.htacess` трогать не надо. Нужно настроить маршруты в laravel.

Конкретно в laravel должен быть маршрут, принимающий любой url, который возвращает страницу инициализации SPA приложения.

К сожалению вы не указали версию laravel, поэтому примем версию `5.5.* - 6.*`
в файле `routes/web.php` надо вместо машрута `/` создать маршут такой (в самом низу)

```php
Route::get('{url}', 'Controller@enty')->where('url', '.*');
```

Comment: Получил такую ошибку - BadMethodCallException
Method [entry] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Controller]. Сейчас поищу версию Laravel.

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",

Comment: Блин, я же для примера написал. Ясное дело, что такого метода не существует. Вставь вместо `Controller@entry` то, значение, которое в маршруте `/` было.

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто я в php вообще ничего не понимать. Laravel так тем более.)  В файле web.php много маршрутов, вида - Route::get('/login', 'Web\LoginController@loginForm')->name('loginForm');, и я не понимаю, что именно вставить вместо Controller@entry.

Comment: Тогда надо содержимое `routes/web.php` предоставить здесь. Никто, кроме вас, не знает, что там написано))

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Можно ведь решить проблему?)

Answer (score 0):

Урлы строятся с хэшом не на стороне laravel, а на стороне angular.

Нужно изменить в машрутизации ангуляра [LocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) на [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy)

Comment: Сделал вот так - {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}, не помогло.

Comment: @Demonmerc а в RouterModule.forRoot(routes) стоит там { useHash: true } ? Если да, то удалить его

Comment: RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes). Вот так стоит. @k0mar

Comment: @Demonmerc https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location нас там интересует включение html5Mode, попробуйте так еще

Comment: у меня angular2, там ведь по другом это делается? <base href="/"> @k0mar